# I need help in making multiple button in one form without performing form action when clicked on save or retrieve

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

"Save" button should save data into a database.  and "retrieve" button should retrieve data from database without performing form action as form action will be will be activated only when clicked on "add" button.

```
<div class="x_content">
              <form id="createUserForm" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>supply_chain/add_new_time_card_in_db" method="POST" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
               <div class="form-group">
               <h4 style="color:#FF0000"><?php if(isset($error) && $error != ''){echo $error; } ?></h4>
               <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Worker_id">Worker Code<span class="required">*</span>
               </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <select  required= "required" name="Worker_id"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                  <option value="null">Choose Worker Code</option>
                  <?php
                  foreach ($workerCodeOptions as $value) {
                   echo "<option value=".$value['Worker_id'].">".$value['Worker_id']."</option>";
                 }
                 ?>
                 </select>
                </div>
               </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                 <h4 style="color:#FF0000"><?php if(isset($error) && $error != ''){echo $error; } ?></h4>
                 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="month">Month<span class="required">*</span>
                 </label>
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input type="text" required="required" name="Month" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="month">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add <?php echo $buttonName?></button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Retrieve Data</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" formaction="<?php echo base_url(); ?>supply_chain/update_time_card">Save Data</button>

                  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>'">Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: You can bind click events to these 2 buttons and use `event.preventDefault()` inside the click handlers to suppress default form submission behaviour.

Comment: Don't use `<button type="submit">`, the `type="submit"` part submits the form

Comment: Not helping if I remove submit as type. @mike510a

Answer (score 0):

return false at the end of the event handler will prevent the submission.

```
<Script>
function retrieveData(){
/* Your code here to retreive data*/
return false;
}
function saveData(){
/* Your code to save data */
return false;
}
</Script>
<form>
<button type="submit"  onclick="return retrieveData()">Retrieve Data</button>
<button type="submit"  onclick="return saveData()">Save Data</button>
</form>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/hca3e0s2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form"  method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="text" placeholder="textbox1" name="textbox1" value="this is value number one" >
<input type="text" placeholder="textbox2" name="textbox2" value="this is value number two" >

<button type="submit" onclick="javascript: form.action='/submit.php';">submit</button>
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript: form.action='/delete.php';">delete</button>
```